# How to create filterable and sortable div elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, filter

I am using rails 3 and ruby 1.9 to develop a ecommerce app. I currently have a loop pulling product info from the database into a div for each product to populate the storefront.

Problem is I have been been trying without any luck to figure out how to make the products sortable and filterable. Basically i want potential customers to be able to filter and/or sort the products listing by some of the data associated with the products (e.g., sort by date added or filter by manufacturer).

So far i've come across some templates using jquery to accomplish this, but i haven't been able to find anything leveraging the rails framework. Ive included the code below. any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="store-header1"><h2>Today's</h2> </div><div class="store-header2"><h2>Offers</h2></div>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="Primary">
    <div class="dots">
<div id="offer-title"> <%= product.title %> </div>
<%= image_tag(product.image_url, :alt =>product.title,  :class=>"product-image")%>
```

Comment: Please format your question, it's unreadable now.

Comment: what do you mean unreadable? are you saying its not clear what im asking?

Comment: I'm saying that you have huge block of text. make paragraphs from it, this is hard to read now!